# Can't fully mount or clone Windows 8.1 hard disk sda2 is missing

Tags: partitioning, mount, data-recovery

Yes I have read at least other 7 articles with similar problems and tried those solutions. But I don't think there is a question like this one.

Windows was failing on a HP pavilion laptop, so I ran all the Windows and HP diagnostics and repair tools available, and most failed. Then I moved to Ubunuto so I could make a data backup and try to do a factory reset (I think that's gonna fail too).

So Windows says it only has two partitions, the small one for the system and the primary one where everything is installed. It doesn't show a hidden HP restore partition.

Clonezilla shows 6 partitions sda1 thru sda6. Being the 450GB primary windows partition sd4. Neither Ubuntu, Windows HP diag tools, nor Clonezilla could mount Windows partition sd4.

The common problem is that Windows 8.1 did not shut down correctly... because it was failing and does not boot any more (cause I tried all Win repairs too, I know it won't). Therefore I cannot enter Windows and shut it down correctly.

With clonezilla I erased the "Dirty Bit" flag on two partitions (wow, not just sda4, and don't know what other, maybe sda2). so the program could be used on those partitions too, since it said it couldn't do it without it being removed.

So it backed up sda1 (500MB system) sda2 (don0t know) sda3(dont know) and sda6(hidden restore partition) but not sda4(450GB partition with all my data). Don't know why it couldn't do it with sda5 or what it is.

Final message of clonezilla is "Broken partition images were found or some of them are not checkable in this iamge: nameofthefile".

So, I just want to mount Windows partition (sda4 in clonezilla, sda2 in ubuntu but not detected by it), recover my files and erase the whole thing. ¿Ideas? Thanks a lot.

```
it@it:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60563 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8eb88495

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

---

When I try to mount it with Nautilus file explorer this is what I get:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/it/Windows: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/it/Windows"' exited with non-zero exit status 18: Failed to write lock '/dev/sda4': Resource temporarily unavailable
Error opening '/dev/sda4': Resource temporarily unavailable
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

---

GPARTED Shows sda1 through sda6. 
sda3 and sda4 both have a red exclamation sign

```
/dev/sda3 REDEXCLAMATION filesystem UNKNOWN 128.00MiB flags:msftres
/dev/sda4 REDEXCLAMATION filesystem NTFS 439.33GB flags:msftdata
```

---

SO after a dd copy the whole sda, it does not copy the whole sda, but only sda5

---

next day: Using chkdsk from a usb win 8.1 installation image.

```
x:\sources>chkdsk C: /f /x /r
Filesystem type is NTFS
label is Windows

Stage 1: file system structure exam:
Can't read from registry segment file 263128
Can't read from registry segment file 263129
Can't read from registry segment file 263130
Can't read from registry segment file 263131
Progress: 263172 of 567296 ended; stage: 46%; total: 0%; Estimated time of arrival: 999:00:00 ..

/*/*/*
567296 registry files processed
File check completed

5578 big file registry processed.
4 unvalid file registries proccesed.

Stage 2: file name link exam...
Deleting entry tmp00000000. on index $I30 from file 20022
Deleting entry TMP000~1. on index $I30 from file 20022
((((((((((around 17 such messages)))))))))))

681490 index entry processed.
index check completed
CHKDKS is examining no indexed files for reconnecting to their original directory
Recovering orfan file DEP-AV~1.GZ (144) on file directory 105252.
((((10 other such messages)))))

25 non indexed files examined.

CHKDSK is recovering remaining non indexed files.
3 non indexed files recovered

Stage 3: security descriptors exam...
CHKDSK is completing the security descriptor sequence
Checking completed
Inserting data attribute on file 2097

57100 data files processed
CHKDKS is checking USN diary.

Stage 4: incorrect cluster search on user data files...
567280 file processed.
Data file checking completed.

Stage 5: Search of available incorrect clusters...
52718263 avaliable clusters processsed.

Checking of available space  is completed.
adding 1 defective cluster to the defective cluster file.
Correcting errors on master file table data attribute (MFT)
Correcting errors on master file table bitmap attribute (MFT)
CHKDSK detected available space marked as used on volume bitmap

Windows has made some corrections to file system.
No other action is required

460665855 kb total space on disk
248994696 kb in 256141 files
```

....other info on disk, and then:

```
Error when transfering session messages to the event registry with state 50
```

**SUCESS!** Even though, Linux froze when copying file with Nautilus. Any way now it boots from windows, will continue copy from there...

Comment: Hi, could you check if the partition show up in `sudo fdisk -l`. If it does could you try mounting it from terminal using `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` and post any errors that it shows.

Comment: I've added the results from fdisk -l only for that disk.

Comment: When I mount that sda1, it only shows two folders "systeminformation" and "recovery"

Comment: I am currently making a full dd copy to my external drive, but it will be nice to know what to do next.

Comment: I have added an answer, check to see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have gpt partition on disk thats why fdisk  doesnt recognize them. `Red exclamation marks` show that the partitions need to be checked for errors.

Try this running `chkdsk` for each partition from  a windows disk, that will fix them. If that is not possible, you can run `ntfsfix` from linux but i would recommend `chkdsk` over it.

Check this tutorial on running `chkdsk` from windows disk https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=6565

After that see if mounting works.

To mount a partition

```
sudo  mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Your files of that partition will then be inside `/mnt`

You can unmount same mounted partition by

```
sudo umount /dev/sda2
```

Try that for all partitions and post errors if you encounter any

Comment: ok then, will do so, but windows 8.1 boot fixes are supposed to run chkdsk, and they do not work. Will run them directly.

Comment: wow and now its taking forever, wich is not unheard with chkdsk. But after 20 minuts of check it estimates 999 hours to finish, and climbing. It is a 500GB HD with around 60% space use.

Comment: If its taking so much time then its quite possible that your disk might be damaged. If chkdisk doesnt correct it try using spinrite. Also think about replacing it if possible.

Comment: well it's finished the process (chkdsk) and apparently it did fix something, will post results above...

Comment: Error when transfering session messages to the event registry with state 50

Comment: SUCESS!!! not even needed to use Spinrite, just wait to chkdsk to finish, back up with ubuntu, and it even boots Windows (I'll replace that damn HD nevertheless)

Comment: @HermesVillafuerte Thats good to hear. Were you able to get your partitions mounted then?

Comment: @HermesVillafuerte Also from your `chkdsk` logs it seems that your mft was corrupted and indeed restored. Many corrupt files seems to have also been restored. Just make **sure** that you backup your data on disk and replace it as soon as possible. Goodluck!!

Comment: much appreciate your help, it can indeed mount the partition now. I beleive it was hibernation the one that made Nautilus freeze, but was not a problem on Windows. I will restore from factory settings, check HD with installed tools, and report to HP to claim the extended warranty (which do not cover data recovery). Anyways backup is in process :-)

Comment: @HermesVillafuerte Glad to be of help. Do tell if you encounter any more problems.